# Pythonic way to replace every second comma of string with space

Tags: python

I have a string which looks like this:

```
coords = "86.2646484375,23.039297747769726,87.34130859375,22.59372606392931,88.13232421875,24.066528197726857"
```

What I want is to bring it to this format:

```
coords = "86.2646484375,23.039297747769726 87.34130859375,22.59372606392931 88.13232421875,24.066528197726857"
```

So in every second number to replace the comma with a space. Is there a simple, pythonic way to do this.

Right now I am trying to do it with using the split function to create a list and then loop through the list. But it seems rather not straightforward.

Comment: `list(zip(c.split(","), c.split(",")[1:]))[::2]`, perhaps? Looks kinda ugly.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First let's import the regular expression module and define your `coords` variable:

```
>>> import re
>>> coords = "86.2646484375,23.039297747769726,87.34130859375,22.59372606392931,88.13232421875,24.066528197726857"
```

Now, let's replace every second comma with a space:

```
>>> re.sub('(,[^,]*),', r'\1 ', coords)
'86.2646484375,23.039297747769726 87.34130859375,22.59372606392931 88.13232421875,24.066528197726857'
```

The regular expression `(,[^,]*),` looks for pairs of commas.  The replacement text, `r'\1 '` keeps the first comma but replaces the second with a space.

Answer (score 3):

This sort of works:

```
>>> s = coords.split(',')
>>> s
['86.2646484375', '23.039297747769726', '87.34130859375', '22.59372606392931', '88.13232421875', '24.066528197726857']
>>> [','.join(i) for i in zip(s[::2], s[1::2])]
['86.2646484375,23.039297747769726', '87.34130859375,22.59372606392931', '88.13232421875,24.066528197726857']
```

Comment: or `[i + ',' + j for i,j in zip(out, out[1:])]`

Answer (score 2):

The pythonic way is to split the string and join it again, with the alternating delimiters:

```
from itertools import chain, cycle, izip
coords = ''.join(chain.from_iterable(izip(coords.split(','), cycle(', '))))
```